# Are question about website architecture off-topic ?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

I would like to know if this question should be consider as off-topic or on-topic.

[Why should I develop my applications using the MVC design pattern?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/527/why-should-i-develop-my-applications-using-the-mvc-design-pattern/551)

2 opinion have been stated in the comment of the question :

> PW is for issues related to running a site, not building it. This would be a great StackOverflow question.

Andres Jaan Tack

> I disagree. The site proposal clearly states it's for "professional webmasters, professional website operators, SEO experts". Webmasters build and maintain. Operators do the running. And SEO experts - well they just empty wallets out for people ;-)

Mark Hatton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO this is not on topic for webmasters -- it has much more to do with programming and the philosophy of programming more than maintaining and operating a website.

(except in the most extreme and abstract terms, in which case it's so abstract it's not that useful of a question, either.)

However, I don't feel *so strongly* that it is off topic that it needs to be closed or deleted. In some of these grey areas it is OK for the community to decide.

Answer (score 4):

I consider that question appropriate on Pro Webmasters, as it is about website architecture, certainly a relevant topic for a webmaster. Technology-specific implementation details would likely be better handled on StackOverflow, but there's no reason the "meta" discussion couldn't happen here.

Answer (score 1):

A 'pro' webmaster can write code (maybe a little, maybe a lot), so I don't think its inherently off topic. However, we're getting into the same overlap with server configuration here .. which a pro webmaster can also typically do.

I think we need our benevolent dictator to chime in, since we're going to (possibly) overlap trilogy sites.

I hate duplicating stuff, and its going to be a while until we can close something due to "Belonging on SO", or SF, etc. That leaves us "off topic", which is kind of hostile, since such questions are on topic here.

There's also the possibility of annoying someone by migrating something only to have it closed as a duplicate on the receiving site.

Meanwhile, we only have a few days left in private beta, so a consensus really should be reached.

Sorry for the non-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line should be drawn between the how and the why.  The questions should be fine if they relate architecture to the why of implementation.  An analogy?  An architect (buildings, not software) needs to know the qualities of the different building materials.  A builder does as well.  If the architect truly groks the materials, they can design and build [amazing things that surprise.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFallingwaterWright.jpg)  Website architecture questions that extend fundamental understanding are appropriate here.